Append row from one df to another
Want to get result as explained below but not getting the desired result.
Tried .update but failed. The last_row should be placed in blank row in its column.
given:::>
import pandas as pd

d1 = {
        'a': [10],
        'b': [20],
        'c': [30],
        'q': "",
        'w': "",
        'e': ""
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print(df1)

d2 = {
        'q': [7,40],
        'w': [8,50],
        'e': [9,60]
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
print(df2)

last_row = df2.tail(1)
print(last_row)

expected result:::>
result = {
    'a': [10],
    'b': [20],
    'c': [30],
    'q': [40],
    'w': [50],
    'e': [60]
}

df_result = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df_result)


Your end goal is not fully clear, I assume you want to update the last row if df1 based on df2. Is this correct? Please clarify the exact expected logic since there are many ways to interpret your question ;)

Need same index in df1 and last_row, here 0:
df1.update(last_row.reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
    a   b   c   q   w   e
0  10  20  30  40  50  60

Another idea is create new columns filled by Series from last_row by DataFrame.assign:
out = df1.assign(**last_row.iloc[0])
print (out)
    a   b   c   q   w   e
0  10  20  30  40  50  60

EDIT:
d1 = { 'a': [10,5,1], 'b': [20,6,2], 'c': [30,7,3], 'q': ["",17,""],
      'w': ["",18,""], 'e': ["",19,""] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {
        'q': [7,40],
        'w': [8,50],
        'e': [9,60]
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
print(df2)

last_row = df2.tail(1).set_axis([df1.index[-1]])
print(last_row)

df1.update(last_row)
print(df1)
    a   b   c     q     w     e
0  10  20  30                  
1   5   6   7    17    18    19
2   1   2   3  40.0  50.0  60.0


first solution works for my initial question. Going further if   d1 = {
'a': [10,5,1],
'b': [20,6,2],
'c': [30,7,3],
'q': ["",17,""],
'w': ["",18,""],
'e': ["",19,""]
}
and expected result is = {'a': [10, 5, 1], 'b': [20, 6, 2], 'c': [30, 7, 3], 'q': ["", 17, '40'], 'w': ["", 18, '50'], 'e': ["", 19, '60']}              what modification to the code is required ?

@Dan - Then is possible set index value by last value of df1.index, answer was edited.

If you goal is to modify the last row of df1, use indexing:
d1 = { 'a': [10,5,1], 'b': [20,6,2], 'c': [30,7,3], 'q': ["",17,""], 'w': ["",18,""], 'e': ["",19,""] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

last_row = df2.tail(1)

df1.loc[df1.index[-1], last_row.columns] = last_row.values

Or with update (which I find more cumbersome):
df1.update(df2.tail(1).set_axis([df1.index[-1]]))

# or
df1.update(df2.tail(1).set_axis(df1.index[-1:]))

Output:
    a   b   c   q   w   e
0  10  20  30            
1   5   6   7  17  18  19
2   1   2   3  40  50  60


@Dan the loc should work too
